# How does the Forgotten tech Learn From Others work?

Tags: endless-legend

I am playing a single player game with *The Forgotten*, the new faction added with the *Shadows* expansion. I am playing on Hard AI difficulty, at Slow game pace. I have unlocked the faction-specific technology, "Learn From Others". The text on this particular tech states the following:

> +3 XP per turn on hero
>   +5 XP per turn per infiltrated hero on hero

It was my assumption that this XP boost is calculated like this:

```
Z = number of infiltrated heroes
[base hero XP] + 3XP + (5XP * Z)
```

I am not seeing results that affirm my assumption. I currently have 8 infiltrated heroes. According to my assumptions, that means all of my heroes should be earning

```
[base XP] + 3XP + (5XP * 8) = [base] + 43XP per turn
```

However, the hero earning the most XP per turn is earning 10 XP total per turn. I will admit that my formula does seem flawed; 43 XP per turn on every hero seems ridiculously overpowered. How exactly does the "Learn From Others" tech increase hero XP gains? What is the formula that is being used by the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumed formula was actually correct; this was a bug. It has now been fixed, but it was also changed. As of writing, the tech is now:

> +3 XP per turn on hero
>   +3 XP per turn per infiltrated hero on hero

See the relevant post on the Amplitude forums for more information:
http://forums.amplitude-studios.com/showthread.php?82776